# What is difference between Interrupted Time Series (ITS) and Regression Discontinuity in Time(RDiT) analysis?

Tags: econometrics, regression, time-series, empirical-methods, rdd

Can anyone give some details on the difference between Interrupted Time Series (ITS) and Regression Discontinuity in Time(RDiT) analysis? How to choose between them? which one is more robust? Or some reference for understanding those.

Thank you